# fscanf reads incorrect value ? -Xcode

Tags: xcode, fopen, output, scanf

I've placed File.rtf in the directory `library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test(projectname)/Build/Products/Debug` and the code seems to open it but prints out the wrong output.The output is `1606422622` for any integer value in the file.

Going through the solutions of question similar to mine ,the answers were to get the input file in the right directory.I think I've done that but I just can't get the correct output.

Desperate for help.Thanks.

```
int main()
{
  int b;
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("File.rtf","r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf( "File doesn't exist!\n");
  }
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&b);
  printf("%i\n",b);

  fclose(fp);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to read a RTF formatted file. Try saving the file as a 'plain text file' in TextEdit. (with extension .txt)

[image]