# C switch "default" not working in desired way

Tags: c, switch-statement, case, default

I am still learning programming, so sorry if there is a simple question. I have a program here that determines if a number is divisible by 23. However, if someone enters a character (which might happen on accident), such as "u," it incorrectly shows that it is indeed divisible by 23. How can I modify this program so that it displays that as an error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double enterednumber;

    printf("This is a test to see if a number is divisible by 23.\nPlease enter a number ");
    scanf("%lg", &enterednumber);

    switch ((int) enterednumber%23)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Yes, %g is divisible by 23\n", enterednumber);
            break;
        default:
            printf("No, %g is not divisible by 23\n", enterednumber);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using `%g` when you seem to want it as an int (`%d`)?

Comment: what does the "l" in `%lg` do here? that seems wrong.

Comment: @BradAllred, I think that is how double is specified to scanf. Another way is `%lf`. See [scanf format codes](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html)

Comment: You should use integers, probably... Not double. But your problem indeed is scanf return value. Always check that!

Comment: @Smac89 thanks, Its been a while since I've used C. I was thinking `%g` was for double and `%f` was for float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always check for errors from your input functions, and don't use the 'value' when the input function says it has not given you a value.

```
if (scanf("%lg", &enterednumber) != 1)
    ...an error occurred, or EOF: do not use value in enterednumber...
```

Your code is odd using a `double` when you are doing integer arithmetic.  You should be using `int` types throughout, avoid the cast and using `%d` for the input and output formats.

---

> So how could I make it so that if someone enters a non-digit that it displays "an error occurred, check number"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int enterednumber;
    int rc;

    printf("This is a test to see if a number is divisible by 23.\nPlease enter a number ");
    if ((rc = scanf("%d", &enterednumber)) != 1)
    {
        if (rc == EOF)
            printf("EOF detected\n");
        else
            printf("Non-number detected\n");
        return 1;
    }

    switch (enterednumber % 23)
    {
    case 0:
        printf("Yes, %d is divisible by 23\n", enterednumber);
        break;
    default:
        printf("No, %d is not divisible by 23\n", enterednumber);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you decide to wrap a loop around the code (so that the user can enter multiple numbers), then you need to clear the error after detecting an invalid input. That's probably most simply done by:

```
    if ((rc = scanf("%d", &enterednumber)) != 1)
    {
        if (rc == EOF)
        {
            printf("EOF detected\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int c;
            printf("Non-number detected\n");
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && !isdigit(c))
                ;
            continue;  // I hypothesized a loop around this!
        }
    }
```

You can decide whether to print the non-numeric characters as they are read.  Another alternative is to read a whole line (with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)), and then use `sscanf()` on the line. This makes it easier to report on what the erroneous text was.

Comment: So how could I make it so that if someone enters a non-digit that it displays "an error occurred, check number"?

Comment: Can you copy and paste that into the right location on my code?

Comment: Jonathan, for an encore, can you send this straight to the in-box of his teacher? `:-P`

Comment: @Jongware: yeah — have you got the email address?

Comment: With any luck it is [this feller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300826/plagiarism-detection-for-obj-c) 

Comment: lol, you guys are cruel. i am actually learning on my own with a library textbook

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your character is being used in your switch based on its ascii value.  Check this link: http://jackstromberg.com/2013/02/how-to-validate-numeric-integer-input-in-c/ to see if you can force your input to be numeric before executing the switch.

Comment: doesn't `scanf` convert the character as whatever the format specifies (double in this case)?

Comment: Nope, scanf does put anything except a double into a double.

Comment: right, but `enterednumber` is a double and he is using `%g` so the problem is that `scanf()` is returning an error I think.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect `scanf()` to do when it encounters something it cannot convert?

A look at [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
's reference page provides you with the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just change from `%g` to `%d`, and use `int` instead of `double` should work as desired:

```
int main(void)
{
    int enterednumber;

    printf("This is a test to see if a number is divisible by 23.\nPlease enter a number ");
    scanf("%d", &enterednumber);

    switch (enterednumber%23)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Yes, %d is divisible by 23\n", enterednumber);
            break;
        default:
            printf("No, %d is not divisible by 23\n", enterednumber);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is it still gives me weird numbers. For example, if i enter "u", I get a response of "No, 1606422622 is not divisible by 23." I just want it to say something like "error" if this happens

Comment: Your Bad Result number is a known one -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823757/fscanf-reads-incorrect-value-xcode for example. If you *ignore bad input* this problem should go away.